# Best way to create a relationship in a mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a database that is similar to the following:

We have 'projects' and projects will consist of multiple 'steps' each step has multiple 'todos'.

The first schema that comes to mind is something like this:

```
{
    project_name: "name",
    due_date: "some date",
    steps: [
        {
            step_name:"name",
            description: "description",
            step_category:"category"
            todos: [
               {
                   todo_name:"name",
                   todo_description: "description",
                   due: "date"
               }
            ]
        }
    ],

}
```

However, I expect to be doing a lot of queries on 'todos' and 'steps'. For example, stats about the individual todos, or todos by category (which would be part of steps), maybe queries ranges from the project due date to get the todos.

My main issue then is what would be the best practice for the 'schema' structure. I think the best way would be to segregate 'projects', 'steps', and 'todos' into their own collections and index their ids and other relevant data for the queries. However, since mongodb is not really relational, I was wondering if this approach scales well. Althought I would not be expecting 'todos' to go above a million documents in a very long time.

Note: I wont be using a relational database because my original case is not really a todo application. I am using this as an example. my 'todos' are entities that will have very varying types with different attributes for each type and it might be prone to changes, which is why I am planning to use mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 210 of [MongoDB: The Definitive Guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-the-definitive/9781491954454/) we have a description of the tree design pattern which sounds similar to the problem you have here where "this pattern can be applied when you have a lot of queries and have data that is hierarchical in structure." I dig further into this and find a tree structure with child references that might be beneficial for what you try to do [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/). For example, let's say we have a schema that looks like this:

[image]

Which can look like this:

```
    db.categories.insertMany( [
{ _id: "Todo 1", todo_name:"name", todo_description: "description", due: "date" },
{ _id: "Todo 2", todo_name:"name", todo_description: "description", due: "date" },
{ _id: "Step 2", description: "description", step_category:"category", children: [ "Todo 1", "Todo 2" ] },
{ _id: "Step 1", description: "description", step_category:"category", children: [] }
{ _id: "Project 1", due_date: $date, children: [ "Step 1, Step 2" ] },
] )
```